# Center labels in Tablelayoutpanel

Tags: c#

I Can not get Labels to "Snap" to The Center of a cell in Tablelayoutpanel.
I tried to Set The anchor to none in the Tablelayoutpanel.TextAlign to center &  AutoSize to false in the Label before dragging it to the Tablelayoutpanel,no joy.The Label just stays at the top left?I want the Label to align with the TextBox I have in it.

Is their some kinda trick to this? or should i be using a other layout panel?

Comment: For the Label control: Anchor=None, Dock=None, AutoSize=True should work

Comment: It's obvious now, I put Anchor=None on the label and boom goes the dynamite!!

Answer (score 15):

Just replace Anchor property of the label from **Top, Left to None**.
[Set None](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFcaV.png)

Answer (score 4):

You should do the following:

1. Set label `AutoSize = false`.
2. Set label Anchor to (Left | Right | Top | bottom)
3. Set Label Text Alignment to Middle-Center..

Worked for me..